# IntelliJ Module Project Structure only allows me to select folders as excluded, but not other options like another project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I started a new Java game project but I can't mark folders as resources/source.

[image]

But I open an example code from the internet with only 3 files and I have the ability to do so. Both are using same java version

[image]

Why does this not let me choose more options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the module and add a new module of the **Java** type. Right now you are using the Static Web module type which doesn't have these settings.